# Generic Method to Serialize json String to Object Syntax

Tags: c#, json, generics, javascriptserializer

I'm just trying to create a generic method here but obviously do not have the syntax right and need help fixing this as I can't see how I can get this working:

```
  private static T SerializeJsonToObject<string,T>(string jsonObjectRepresentationsToDeserialize, T typeToDeserializeTo)
    {
        T serializedTypeFromJson = _jsonSerializer.Deserialize(jsonObjectRepresentationsToDeserialize, typeToDeserializeTo);

        return serializedTypeFromJson;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could always do:

```
private static T SerializeJsonToObject<T>(string jsonObjectRepresentationsToDeserialize)
{
    return _jsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonObjectRepresentationsToDeserialize);
}
```

usage

```
MyObject obj = SerializeJsonToObject<MyObject>("json object");
```